Is Hutchinson's trick $\operatorname E\left[\langle V,AV\rangle\right]=\sigma^2\operatorname{tr}A$ of any practical use?
Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $A\in\mathbb R^d$. Hutchinson's trick is the easy to prove observation that if $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ is a probability space and $(V_1,\ldots,V_d)$ is a real-valued independent identically distributed process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$\operatorname E\left[V_1\right]=0\tag1$$ and $$\sigma^2:=\operatorname{Var}[V_1],$$ then $$\operatorname E\left[\langle V,AV\rangle\right]=\sigma^2\operatorname{tr}A.\tag2$$ Consequentially, we could estimate $\operatorname{tr}A$ by choosing $k\in\mathbb N$ and generating a real-valued independent identically distributed process $(V_{ij})_{\substack{1\le i\le k\\1\le j\le d}}$ with $$\operatorname E\left[V_{11}\right]=0\tag3$$ and $$\sigma^2:=\operatorname{Var}[V_{11}].$$ Then, $$\frac1{k\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^k\langle V_i,AV_i\rangle\approx\operatorname{tr}A\tag4.$$ If you need motivation why we would want to estimate $\operatorname{tr}A$ at all, see below.
Now, for $k\ge d$, this idea is obviously stupid, since we could simply compute $$\operatorname{tr}A=\sum_{i=1}^d\langle e_i,Ae_i\rangle\tag5,$$ where $(e_1,\ldots,e_d)$ denotes the standard basis of $\mathbb R^d$, in this case. However, here is a simple example: Just take $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,2,3)$ and sample $V_{ij}$ independently from the standard normal distribution. For a, I'd say reasonable, choice like $k=3$ I get an output of $7.978185$; while the actual solution is $\operatorname{tr}A=6$. For $k=10$ I get $4.929106$. Even for $k=100000$, I get an output of $6.0087934$, which is still relatively off considering the high sample count.

Question: Given these results, it seems like this method is not practicably useful at all. Am I missing something? Does the situation somehow change in my actual application described below? There I've considered the simple example $f(x)=\|x\|^2$, where the true solution is $\operatorname{tr}A=2d$. The results of the described method are off by the same error magnitude as in the simple scenario above. So, what can we do here? Clearly, the reason why I'm considering this at all is that I don't want to compute the Jacobian of $g$, since the $d$ in my application can be as large as $1\text e6$. Is the normal distribution the problem? Would another distribution yield better results?

EDIT: What I can add: In the application, $A$ is the Jacobian of $g$. Computing the desired quantity by first computing $A$ requires the computation of $d^2$ derivatives. Using $(c)$ instead, we only need $kd$ derivatives. However, again, with then clearly only makes sense for $k<d$.

In my application $$A=\nabla^2f(x)$$ (the Hessian) for some $f\in C^2(\mathbb R^d)$ and $x\in\mathbb R^d$. I don't know $f$ itself, I only know $$g:=\nabla f$$ and I want to compute $$\nabla\cdot g(x)=\operatorname{tr}A\tag a.$$ I actually also don't know $g$ analytically, which is why I'm using auto-differentiation to numerically compute derivatives of $g$. To do so, I modified the estimation above in the following way: Let $$h(z):=\sum_{i=1}^k\langle g(z),V_i\rangle\;\;\;\text{for }z\in\mathbb R^{k\times d}.$$ Then notice that $$\nabla h\underbrace{(x,\ldots,x)}_{k\text{ times}}=\left(\nabla\langle g(x),V_i\rangle\right)_{1\le i\le k}\tag b$$ (I'm identifying $\mathbb R^{k\times d}\cong\mathbb R^{kd}$ all the time; hopefully it's intuitive to you). Given that, we obtain $$\frac1k\left\langle V,\nabla h\underbrace{(x,\ldots,x)}_{k\text{ times}}\right\rangle=\frac1k\sum_{i=1}^k\langle V_i,AV_i\rangle\tag c$$ and the left-hand side is suitable for usage with auto-differentiation.
